# Logic to find if words are present in text in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, text, nlp

I have a string and a list of words which i want to check in case those are present in given text string . I am using the below logic.....is there any other way to optimize it :-

```
import re
text="""
Python is an interpreted, object-oriented, high-level programming language with dynamic semantics.
Its high-level built in data structures, combined with dynamic typing and dynamic binding, make
it very attractive for Rapid Application Development"""
tokens_text=re.split(" ",text)
list_words=["programming","Application"]
if (len(set(list_words).intersection(set(tokens_text)))==len(list_words)):
    print("Match_Found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`set.issubset(other)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) operation:

```
text="""
Python is an interpreted, object-oriented, high-level programming language with dynamic semantics.
Its high-level built in data structures, combined with dynamic typing and dynamic binding, make
it very attractive for Rapid Application Development"""
tokens = text.split()
list_words = ["programming", "Application"]

if (set(list_words).issubset(set(tokens))):
    print("Match_Found")
```

Or simply with `all` function:

```
if all(x in tokens for x in list_words):
    print("Match_Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python’s in operator, i do not know if it is faster.

```
str = "Messi is the best soccer player"

"soccer" in str
-> True

"football" in str
-> False
```

Comment: It will take more time as it will be in for loop for every element .Also i want to check incase both these words in list are present in text. I don't think it willl help in that case ..

Comment: Yeah, you would have loop the search string aswell, best of luck :)